Conflicting Stripe webhook events for successful payment despite invoice.payment_succeeded
I have configured my Stripe webhook to listen for both invoice.payment_failed and invoice.payment_succeeded events. However, despite a successful payment, I am encountering a scenario where I receive conflicting webhook events indicating both success and failure for the same transaction.
To clarify, the payment process itself is completing successfully, and the funds are being processed correctly. However, I'm puzzled as to why I'm still receiving webhook notifications for payment failure.
What I've Tried:

Verified webhook endpoint configuration and ensured it's correctly set up to receive events.
Checked Stripe dashboard for any anomalies or errors related to the transaction, but found none.
Reviewed my code logic to confirm that there are no inadvertent errors causing this behavior.

Upon a successful payment, I expect to receive only the invoice.payment_succeeded webhook event and not the invoice.payment_failed event. The receipt of conflicting events is causing confusion and potentially disrupting downstream processes.stripe events

It's a bit hard to say what could be going on without more specific context. It's possible that you're seeing expected behavior for the Payment Method type that you're letting the customer use to pay for the Invoice. It's also unclear whether more than one payment attempt is being made for the Invoice, in which case the described behavior may be expected if the first payment attempt fails. If you're working with an immediate notification payment method type, and aren't making multiple payments, then that sounds unexpected. I'd recommend writing into Stripe Support to have them take a look.

Is the payment going through 3DSecure? If so, invoice.payment_failed would be expected. While it's not surfaced at payment_intent or charge levels, the requirement for 3DSecure would lead to a failed Charge with authentication_required. I believe this Charge would be completely invisible to you unless you have a higher Stripe Radar plan. In any case, if this is too misleading for your implementation, I would suggest listening of other events like invoice.paid, payment_intent.succeeded and payment_intent.payment_failed, which would not replicate this behavior.

Just noticed the payment_intent.requires_action event from your file, which would seem to confirm my theory.
